# How View Custom Type Set By ACF In My WordPress Controller

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I Am Programmer in Windows Application
I Use This Library In My Project :
https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL/wiki/Create-post-with-custom-type
In Above Link Description : This Library Supported Of AFC .
But Programmer Need Know AFC : Where And What set in Rest Api
Main Problem is : I Used above Library And Need what post data until make new post in post category define by me in WordPress .
Please See ScreenShot Of ACF Fields in WordPress :
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/955f/zvqv16i4u852qntzg.jpg
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/4b0d/vn4bo4ezm8kgnoazg.jpg

My Question Is : Repeater Field which i Mark in second screenshot how determine and which set for two or three or five and etc values repeat
Thx My Friends

Answer (score 0):

Hope I noticed your problem

In this image you can see 2 Rectangle:

blue Rectangle is : when you have a repeater field, every subfield repeat

and

in red Rectangle you can set howmany times user can repeat it

open image by this link : [a link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/z906sjc5tsn0qca/22.jpg/file)